# Add a centre Line to bootstrap grid, without interfering with existing layouts

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create an effect a bit like [this](http://www.akita.co.uk/computing-history/) with the white line and circles running down the center of a one-page layout, using bootstrap 3.

I thought that the easiest way to do this would be to have a `md-col-6` column running down the whole layout with a right border. However, this is obviously not the way my page needs to be laid out to contain my content, for example, one element is a centered image. Is there a way of creating this effect responsively without interfering with my existing bootstrap grid layout? Ideally, it would be great if there is a generic way of doing this, possibly overlaying another grid (not sure if that is possible). If not, here is a sample of my layout:

```
<div class="container fullheight" >
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <h3 style="font-size:46px;">2012</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row width90">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-7"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-5 right-fact">
      <h3>Tile</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center"> <img src="Images/Image1.svg" alt="Image" height="450px"> </div>
  <div class="row width90">
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-5 left-fact">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- A few repeats to create a onepage website effect -->
```

Comment: Please post relevant code. We don't even know what your existing layout/content looks like.

Comment: @DPac I have edited my question. However, if possible I was really after something generic if it exists, so it isn't dependent on the content of my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```css
.middle-line {
  position: fixed;
  height: calc(80vh - 28px); 
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1px;
  left: 50%;
  
  background-color: black;
}
.middle-line:before {
  border: 5px solid black;
  
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;

  display: block;
  content: '';
  bottom: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle-line"></div>
```

Feel free to change the color of the line and of the circle by changing the two instances of `black` from CSS if you want another color. For example, replacing it with `rgba(255,255,255,.85)` will make them white with 85% opacity. You can also modify the size of the circle and the width of the border until you're happy with the result.

Don't forget to add the `html` in your page :). It's small, but important. You can place it anywhere inside `<body>`, preferably as a direct child.

Cheers!